# How to debug "broken dependencies" during dnf update?

Tags: rpm, dependencies, dnf

When trying to update packages using `dnf`, some packages are skipped because of "broken dependencies":

```
$ sudo dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:38 ago on Mon Feb  6 12:05:50 2017.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package             Arch   Version                    Repository          Size
================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
... packages ...

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Skip  8 Packages
```

How can I find what the problem actually is? Like package `x` requires package `y` in version `z` that can't be found.

Dnf version: 1.1.10
Operating system: Fedora 25

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo dnf update --best`

Sample output:

```
Error: package vdsm-cli-4.20.0-261.gitabb73a5.fc25.noarch requires vdsm-client = 4.20.0-261.gitabb73a5.fc25, but none of the providers can be installed.
package vdsm-cli-4.20.0-261.gitabb73a5.fc25.noarch requires vdsm-python = 4.20.0-261.gitabb73a5.fc25, but none of the providers can be installed
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages)
```

From [documentation](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html):

> -b, --best
>       Try the best available package versions in transactions. Specifically during dnf upgrade, which by default skips over updates that can not be installed for dependency reasons, the switch forces DNF to only consider the latest packages. When running into packages with broken dependencies, DNF will fail giving a reason why the latest version can not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually download the problematic RPM using `wget` then try to install it by hand using `dnf install PACKAGE`. This usually gives me more detailed information about the dependency problems.